# Alternative to TCP/IP for local program-to-program data streaming?

Tags: c++, python, linux, networking, gcc

I have a GNU C++ program and a python script that need to pass strings to each other quite frequently (~70-80 messages a minute). They will run local to each other in CentOS (hosted in the same environment). It feels that although TCP/IP can and will get the job done, what other options do I have?

Keep in mind that I cannot turn my C++ program into a SO and integrate it into my python script using ctypes, my C++ program must be compiled in 32bit, and my python script must be 64bit.

Comment: What prompted your concern? Is there some reason why you are not satisfied with using TCP/IP? It will be hard to usefully recommend an alternative without knowing what problem you are having with TCP.

Comment: General curiousity and a nagging feeling that TCP/IP feels...unnecessary. You dont really need the whole flow control/delivery guarantees/ handshaking that the protocol provides.

Comment: 70-80 messages per minute is such a low rate that spending any time optimizing the IPC mechanism is a waste of time.  Whatever you can code the fastest is the best choice.  I don't know what your C++ program is, but I would seriously reconsider whether you should just write the whole thing in python and avoid message passing altogether.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you already have a TCP or UDP server, the easiest way will probably be to switch to UNIX domain sockets.

They come in "stream" and "datagram" modes, just like TCP/UDP sockets, and they're always local, as they use the filesystem namespace (instead of port numbers like TCP/UDP).

Comment: +1, I'm a fan of this approach because it allows you to easily separate the two processes onto different boxes in the future with a minimum of code rewrites.

Comment: But what advantage does using UNIX domain sockets have over using TCP/UDP sockets?

Comment: what are the pros and cons of using domain sockets over tcp/ip?

Comment: With TCP and UDP you use up a port. Sure, you can bind to localhost only, but it's still a port. If someone configures it wrong and makes it listen on all interfaces, it could be attacked from somewhere else. And then there's the IPv4/IPv6 switchover that's starting to happen. Headaches all around.

With UNIX domain sockets, you can just create more sockets anywhere in the filesystem where you have write access. And you can always rewrite it to use TCP/UDP if (and when!) the need arises.

Comment: @Rob: You can use UNIX permissions to control access to UNIX domain sockets; you can pass file descriptors over UNIX domain sockets; you can pass kernel-verified PID, UID and GID credentials; and you can use `SOCK_SEQPACKET` with UNIX domain sockets.

Answer (score 5):

Named pipes are the standard method.  In Python:

```
import os

os.mkfifo('/some/path')

# Reading process

with open('/some/path') as pipe:
    for line in pipe:
        # Do what you need

# Writing process

with open('/some/path', 'w') as pipe:
    while True: # Whatever looping process you have
        pipe.write('<data>' + '\n')
```

Note that, on modern systems, 70-80 messages / min is not all that high, TCP is still a viable option.  Also be careful that no one string is larger than the pipe buffer size (generally 64K).

Based on the suggestions in the comments, I've also added an example of UNIX domain sockets, which are more useful if you need bidirectional communication.

```
# Server Side

import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind("/some/path")

sock.listen(1)
conn, addr = sock.accept()

while True:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data:
        break

    # Let's echo it back as an example
    conn.send(data)

conn.close()

# Client Side

import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect("/some/path")

while True: # Your sending loop
    # In this case we send hello world, and print what we get back.
    sock.send('Hello, world')
    data = sock.recv(1024)

    print data

sock.close()
```

Comment: would you know how it would look like on the c++ end? I'm not sure what library does this.

Comment: Named pipes are unidirectional though. UNIX domain sockets are bidirectional, so would probably be better for "exchanging messages".

Comment: @user1040625 It's treated as a file, so you can use the standard fopen / fread / fwrite calls.  `mkfifo` is available in sys/stat.h.

Answer (score 2):

http://tldp.org/LDP/tlk/ipc/ipc.html

- Pipes
- Named Pipes
- TCP Sockets
- UNIX-domain Sockets
- Message Queues
- Shared Memory

By far, I'd prefer TCP sockets.

1. You've already written the support for them,
2. They work equally well inter- as well as intra- machine.
3. There are wonderful tools to debug the communications channel.
4. There are libraries to assist in their use.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use named pipes?